# How to check whether Google TTS voice data installed for Hindi Language

Tags: android

I am using Google TTS Engine for Text-to-speech for Hindi Language.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTIVITY_TTS_PASS:
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);
            int availability = tts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("hin-IND"));
            switch(availability) {
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("TTS", "Language available");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                Log.d("TTS", "Language not supported");

                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
                languages.add("hin-IND"); // hin - hindi, IND - INDIA
                installTTSIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(
                        TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR, languages);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA:
                Log.d("TTS", "Language missing data");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("TTS", "Contry available");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("TTS", "default");
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("TTS", "fail");
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
            languages.add("hin-IND"); // hin - hindi, IND - INDIA
            installTTSIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR, languages);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }

        break;
    default:
        Log.d("TTS", "case default");
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

This is how i can check whether TTS data is installed and Hindi language is supported or not.
This Intent gives option to install voice data for some languages. Then i selected Hindi (India) and installed.

Even after that
    tts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("hin-IND"));
returns TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED.

Also tried with "hi-IN" instead "hin-IND", it gives the same result.
Now voice data is installed but how can i check it by code ?

Answer (score 0):

"hi_IN" is the locale for Hindi(India). Checking for the availability tts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("hi-IN")) works fine after onInit(int result) methode called. So initiate the tts instance in onActivityResult methode and check for availability in onInit methode.

**UPDATE 2017**
Posing code to use TTS on request.

To check if tts data exists:

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

OnActivityResult method will be called

```
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            initTTS();
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
            languages.add("hin-IND"); // hin - hindi, IND - INDIA
            installIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR, languages);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

initTTS method is as follows:

```
private TextToSpeech mTts;
public void initTTS() {
    //mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    mTts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

                int isLanguageAvailable = t1.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("hi_IN"));
                switch (isLanguageAvailable) {
                    case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE:
                        //t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                        t1.setLanguage(new Locale("hin"));
                        t1.setPitch(1.2f);
                        t1.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "हाँ, मैं हिंदी बोल सकता हूँ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        t1.speak("हाँ, मैं हिंदी बोल सकता हूँ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);

                        break;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "TTS initialization Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you post your code because i need check where user device support hindi or not

Comment: for what `ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA` is used here? you didn't set any extras to the intent, how does it know which language to check?

Comment: @user924 This Action is to check for the presence of the TTS resources. (Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA ). Once you get the success result, you can check for specific languages by creating TTS instance. You can explore details about it here https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Comment: `Language_AVAILABLE` doesn't mean that the voice data is installed for that language.

Comment: For future references.

Downvoting since it doesn't answer the question. Also, `isLanguageAvailable` API though mentions that it can return `LANG_MISSING_DATA` but it never does. So afaik, there isn't any text to speech API available to see if the voice data is installed for a particular language. There's one way though https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317988/6671572 as suggested by this answer but it only works in API 21 +